# r - levenshtein distance and UTF-8 encoding

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8, levenshtein-distance, linguistics

I need to calculate the `levenshtein.distance` of the package `vwr` of all the words listed in a column of a csv file, in all possible combinations.

```
library("vwr")

wlfreq <- read.csv(freq, header=TRUE)

# wlfreq is a data frame, we need to select the first column where the words are and then convert them in a list
# words <- as.list(wlfreq[-(1:37),1]) # this solution doesn't seem to work (probably because it actually converts values in factors)
words <- tail(wlfreq, -37) #eliminate first 37 rows (useless for our purposes)
wordlist <- words$Word #subset the first column
wordlist <- as.list(wordlist) #treat it as a list
names(wordlist) <- wordlist #assign the name of the words to the list items

ld.wordlist <- lapply(wordlist, function(x) levenshtein.distance(x, wordlist)) #apply the levenshtein distance to all words, in all possible pairwise combinations
```

However, it encounters an error:

> Error in do_dist(a = b, b = a, method = method, weight = weight, maxDist = maxDist,  : 
>     Encountered byte sequence not representing an utf-8 character.

As matter of fact, `stri_enc_mark()` shows that the wordlist has mixed encoding:

```
[1] "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII"
[11] "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII"
[21] "ASCII" "ASCII" NA      NA      "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII"
[31] "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII"
[41] "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII" "ASCII"
[51] etc
```

To convert all values to UTF-8, I am trying to use the following command:

```
df <- iconv(df$Word, to="UTF=8")
```

but I don't seem to succeed, as the encoding remains the same.

Any hint?

Comment: maybe try `df$Word <- iconv(df$Word, to="UTF=8")`

Comment: nope - I get that all the UTF-8-encoded values are now `NA`...

Comment: have to see ur dataset to understand better

Comment: That "=" should ahve been a "-". But .. Is it even possible to have a vector with mix encoding??????

Comment: I wondered about the same thing...apparently it is! It is a csv file from which I extracted a column of character vector. Please see further info in the question.